# JSON Parse nested objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch

I'm fetching data in React from a MySQL database. MySQL auto-escapes my values including nested objects. I'm using the `.json()` function on the top-level but i'm not able to use this on sub-levels, nor `JSON.parse(response[0].data)` will work.

**What is the right way of doing this?**

```
 fetch(`http://localhost:3000/getQuiz${window.location.pathname}`, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    //   {
    //     "id": 1,
    //     "url": "asd2q13",
    //     "data": "{name: \"Marie\", answers:[\"1\", \"3\", \"0\"]}"
    // }
    console.log(typeof response)
    // object
    console.log(response[0].data)
    // {name: "Marie", answers:["1", "3", "0"]}
    console.log(typeof response[0].data)
    // string
    console.log(response[0].data.name)
    // undefined
  })
```

Comment: I assume this is because it does not like `{name: "Marie", answers:["1", "3", "0"]}` missing quotes around the property names. The [JSON spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) specifies an object member being *string name-separator value* (section 2.2) it further goes on to state that *A string begins and ends with quotation marks* (section 2.5). So the property names in the "JSON" stored in the data property are invalid. Does JSON.parse() throw an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response.data` is not a valid JSON string. You can try:

```js
const response = {
  "id": 1,
  "url": "asd2q13",
  "data": "{name: \"Marie\", answers:[\"1\", \"3\", \"0\"]}"
}
console.log(eval('(' + response.data + ')'))
```

Or Better:

```js
const response = {
  "id": 1,
  "url": "asd2q13",
  "data": "{name: \"Marie\", answers:[\"1\", \"3\", \"0\"]}"
}

function looseJsonParse(obj) {
  return Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')();
}

console.log(looseJsonParse(response.data))
```

But,

> Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use `eval()`. See [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!), below.

I suggest you serialize the `data` correctly on the backend. I think the MySQL database driver can do this. Also, see [Parsing JSON (converting strings to JavaScript objects)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#parsing_json_converting_strings_to_javascript_objects)

Comment: Thank you, it seems reasonable, I'll do some troubleshooting in the database end.

Comment: @RustyJames Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (MySQL2) for Node was the big problem here. It's suppose to serialize "automatically", but somehow it ends up all wrong.

If I do `JSON.Stringify()` explicitly for the nested part before storeing it in the database it works!

```
    const sendToDatabase = () => {
       let nested = JSON.stringify({ name: "Marie", answers: ["2", "1", "0"] })
       let post = { url: "asd2q13", data: nested} 
       var query = connection.query(
           "INSERT INTO users SET ?  ", post,
           function (error, results, fields) {
               if (error) throw error;
           }
       );
       console.log(query.sql); 
   };
```

Then I call this on the front end

```
   console.log(JSON.parse(response[0].data).name)
   // Marie (string)
   console.log(JSON.parse(response[0].data).answers)
   // ["2", "1", "0"] (array)
```

The raw output from this is

```
{"name":"Marie","answers":["2","1","0"]}
```

insted of

```
{name: \"Marie\", answers:[\"1\", \"3\", \"0\"]}
```